# How to modify WindowsXP Registry Key name in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, windows-registry

I want to create the automated malware analysis in my Linux Mint OS and It's have to use the virtualbox to install WindowsXP as GuestOS and now I have successfully installed a WindowsXP on virtual box with Linux Mint 10 as host. but when i'm open the "Registry Editor" and go to "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\IDE" I will see the Device Registry Key like this

http://dropmocks.com/mS8M1

It's have "VBOX"  in key name!! Can I change it ?

PS. for someone who don't understand why I want to change that key name. Because some virus can check the Registry to make it known that is Real Machine or Virtual Machine and It wouldn't do anything if it run on Virtual Machine !! Can anyone help me ? T^T

Sorry for my bad english!!

Comment: I've never done that, but I guess it has been set at install/startup/os install phase by looking up the name of the hardware device. Then I guess that name comes from the VDI disk image of VBx. Idk if it is possible to edit this name within VDI nor if changing the key won't make your guest crash nor if changing in VDI would change it on next startup. Take this as a hint.